# Store the value of selection in variable and pass it to another function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have input from one function in below way

```
function Start-MenuList 
{
    $counter = 0

    "Below are boxes`n"

     Get-Content -Path 'abc.txt' | 
     ForEach {
        $counter++
        "$counter : Press $counter to select $(($PSItem -split '=')[0]) : $(($PSItem -split '=')[1])"
     }

     Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease enter a selection"
}

Clear-Host 
Start-MenuList

    1. Press 1 to select abc : abcde1234
    2. Press 2 to select def : abcde5678
    3. Press 3 to select chi : abcde9090
    Please make a selection:
```

Here if I select 1 as input in selection then I want to store the value for e.g. if I select 1 then it should store "abc" and "abcdef1234" in some variables and pass it to another function and display what we have in those two variables

```
func1 env boxname
```

file abc.txt

```
abc=abcde0001
def=abcedf002
ghj=abcefgh003
```

Comment: Don't forget, we don't have access to your file `abc.txt`, so it's helpful if you include its contents (even if we can infer it from the above). This just makes things quicker, and easier, for us to replicate your problem.

Comment: Lamu - We actually do have this. The OP is posting a followup question from this Q&A that I responded to him on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555254/nested-foreach-loop-in-powershell/60555597#60555597

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you are after:

```
function Start-MenuList 
{
    $counter = 0

    "Below are boxes`n"

     Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\abc.txt' | 
     ForEach {
        $counter++
        "$counter : Press $counter to select $(($PSItem -split '=')[0]) : $(($PSItem -split '=')[1])"
     }

     $s = Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease enter a selection"

     $l = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\abc.txt' | Select-Object -Index ($s-1)
     $c1 = ($l -split '=')[0]
     $c2 = ($l -split '=')[1]

     #Write-Host $c1
     #Write-Host $c2
}

Clear-Host 
Start-MenuList
```

Comment: @Lamu this gives you below error  Select-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Index'. The -1 argument is less than the minimum allowed range of 0. Supply an argument that is greater than or equal to 0 and then try the
command again.

Comment: Seems like you're inputting a too low value, @unknown . You didn't ever supply that sample file, so I had to guess what it looked like, and I got not errors with what I guessed it looked like.

Comment: @Lamu    abc=abcde0001
def=abcedf002
ghj=abcefgh003

Comment: @lamu I have added in my question as well

Comment: it looks the issue is not in the code but when user doesn't give anything in selection then it gives this error

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a follow-up question from the previous Q&A you submitted, This is really as simple as this.

Using your file from the [previous Q&A and my response to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555254/nested-foreach-loop-in-powershell/60555597#60555597).

```
function Start-MenuList 
{
    $counter = 0

    "Below are boxes`n"

     Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\abc.txt' | 
     ForEach {
        $counter++
        "$counter : Press $counter to select $(($PSItem -split '=')[0]) : $(($PSItem -split '=')[1])"
     }

     ($UserChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease enter a selection")
}

Clear-Host 
Start-MenuList

<#
Below are boxes

1 : Press 1 to select a : abcdef123
2 : Press 2 to select b : ngh567
3 : Press 3 to select c : defh123

Please enter a selection: 1
1
#>
```

Of course, you can change the code to grab any part of that displayed menu option for whatever use you'd need, using If/then, try/catch, switch statement etc.

***Example:***

```
function Start-MenuList 
{
    $counter = 0

    "Below are boxes`n"

     Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\abc.txt' | 
     ForEach {
        $counter++
        "$counter : Press $counter to select $(($PSItem -split '=')[0]) : $(($PSItem -split '=')[1])"
     }

     $UserChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease enter a selection"

     switch ($UserChoice) 
         { 
             1 {'abcde1234'} 
             2 {'abcde5678'} 
             3 {'abcde9090'} 
             default {Write-Warning -Message 'No select was made.'}
         }
}

Clear-Host 
Start-MenuList


<#
# Results

Below are boxes

1 : Press 1 to select a : abcdef123
2 : Press 2 to select b : ngh567
3 : Press 3 to select c : defh123

Please enter a selection: 1
abcde1234
#>
```

Now, of course, that it is a hardcoded response, and dynamically, it's can be something like this.

```
function Start-MenuList 
{
    $counter = 0

    "Below are boxes`n"

     Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\abc.txt' | 
     ForEach {
        $counter++
        "$counter : Press $counter to select $(($PSItem -split '=')[0]) : $(($PSItem -split '=')[1])"
     }

     $UserChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease enter a selection"

     switch ($UserChoice) 
         { 
             $UserChoice {"The user selected $UserChoice"} 
             default {Write-Warning -Message 'No select was made.'}
         }
}

Clear-Host 
Start-MenuList

<#
Below are boxes

1 : Press 1 to select a : abcdef123
2 : Press 2 to select b : ngh567
3 : Press 3 to select c : defh123

Please enter a selection: 3
The user selected 3
#>
```

If you want the string from the file/menu, you can still use the switch with an array from the file

```
function Start-MenuList 
{
    $counter = 0

    "Below are boxes`n"

     Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\abc.txt' | 
     ForEach {
        $counter++
        "$counter : Press $counter to select $(($PSItem -split '=')[0]) : $(($PSItem -split '=')[1])"
     }

     $UserChoice = (Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease enter a selection") - 1

     $MenuArray = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\abc.txt') -replace '.*='
     switch ($MenuArray[$UserChoice]) 
         { 
             $MenuArray[$UserChoice] {"The user selected $($MenuArray[$UserChoice])."} 
             default {Write-Warning -Message 'No select was made.'}
         }
}


Clear-Host 
Start-MenuList

<#
Below are boxes

1 : Press 1 to select a : abcdef123
2 : Press 2 to select b : ngh567
3 : Press 3 to select c : defh123

Please enter a selection: 1
The user selected abcdef123.

 Start-MenuList
Below are boxes

1 : Press 1 to select a : abcdef123
2 : Press 2 to select b : ngh567
3 : Press 3 to select c : defh123

Please enter a selection: 2
The user selected ngh567.

 Start-MenuList
Below are boxes

1 : Press 1 to select a : abcdef123
2 : Press 2 to select b : ngh567
3 : Press 3 to select c : defh123

Please enter a selection: 3
The user selected defh123.
#>
```